# How to get js code to display under chrome developer console when running the code in vscode

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, console.log

I am using vscode to learn javascript but for some reason whenevr i run the code `console.log = ('hello world');` in the `.js` file or using `script` tag in the body of the html file nothing shows up in chrome developer console section. But if i use alert in `.js` or `html` the normal display is there.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because you use it in wrong way

```
console.log("hello")
```

not

```
console.log = "hello"
```